# Saving character columns with double quotes ("")

Tags: r, string, character, double-quotes

I want to save string columns containing spaces or blanks with double quotes.

```
df <-
  structure(list(type = c("menu", "item", "item", "item", "item", 
    "item"), menu.item = c("fileMenu", "fileMenu", "fileMenu", "fileMenu", 
    "fileMenu", "fileMenu"), operation.parent = c("topMenu", "command", 
    "separator", "command", "command", "command"), label = c("", 
    "Change working directory...", "", "Open script file...", "Save script...", 
    "Save script as..."), command.menu = c("", "Setwd", "", "loadLog", 
    "saveLog", "saveLogAs"), activation = c("", "", "", "", "", ""
    ), install. = c("", "", "", "", "", "")), .Names = c("type", 
    "menu.item", "operation.parent", "label", "command.menu", "activation", 
    "install."), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"
    )

df
type menu.item operation.parent                       label command.menu

1 menu  fileMenu          topMenu                                         
2 item  fileMenu          command Change working directory...        Setwd
3 item  fileMenu        separator                                         
4 item  fileMenu          command         Open script file...      loadLog
5 item  fileMenu          command              Save script...      saveLog
6 item  fileMenu          command           Save script as...    saveLogAs
  activation install.
1                    
2                    
3                    
4                    
5                    
6      
df$label
[1] ""                            "Change working directory..."
[3] ""                            "Open script file..."        
[5] "Save script..."              "Save script as..."
```

Comment: how about `dQuote(df$label)`? if you needed this for all columns, then `df[] <- lapply(df, dQuote)` works (though it'll happily quote non-`character` if you have them).

Comment: Do you want the double quotes to actually be part of the data? Or do you want the console to print them when you print the data frame? Or do you want to save data frame to a file and have the quotes included there? `print(df, quote = T)` might be all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this:

```r
df$label
#> [1] ""                            "Change working directory..."
#> [3] ""                            "Open script file..."        
#> [5] "Save script..."              "Save script as..."
```

And you want to wrap the contents with double quotes you could do something like:

```r
df$label <- paste0('"', df$label, '"')
df$label

#> [1] "\"\""                            "\"Change working directory...\""
#> [3] "\"\""                            "\"Open script file...\""        
#> [5] "\"Save script...\""              "\"Save script as...\""
```

**To update all columns at once**

Using base R (adapted from comment by @r2evans)

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) paste0('"', x, '"'))
```

Or if you prefer to use something like `dplyr` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate_all(df, ~ paste0('"', ., '"'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace your `""` with `'""'`.

Comment: @MYaseen208 you mean something like this? `df$command.menu %>% stringr::str_replace_all('\\""', '""')`